# Is it possible to pass arguments to a form in Drupal 8?

Tags: yaml, form-api, drupal-8

Picture a YAML routing configuration like this one:

```
foobar.example:
  path: 'example/{entity_type}/{bundle_name}'
  defaults:
    _form: '\Drupal\foobar\Form\FoobarExampleForm'
    _title: 'Example Form'
    foo: 0
    bar: 1
```

Arguments foo and bar would be passed on to a controller, but how do you pass arguments to forms?  I realize entity_type and bundle_name can be retrieved with arg() or menu_get_object().  Are there any other ways to pass arguments to forms?

Answer (score 3):

If you're asking about passing additional values into a form that is not being loaded by a route you do it like this:

```
public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $item = array()) { 
  // Form code here
}
```

And when you call it, do it like so

```
$form = \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm('\Drupal\MYMODULE\Form\MYFORMCLASS', $item);
```

IMPORTANT: If, when you declare your function, you don't give it a default value, you will get a PHP Fatal. So don't do this (without the = array()):

```
public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $item) {
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get variables (foo and bar) like this one

```
public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $foo = NULL, $bar = 1) {
   echo $foo;
   echo $bar;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I think it's possible not the best solution, but arg() can help you. Calling in the form arg(0) will give you 'example', arg(1) gives the {entity_type} and arg(2) the {bundle_name}